# How to ensure I get the picture is complete? (in java)

Tags: java

i using below code to get a picture from URL:

```
    URL url=new URL("http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png");
    InputStream in=url.openStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream tmpOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[512];
    int len;
    while (true) {
        len = in.read(buf);
        if (len == -1) {
            break;
        }
        tmpOut.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    tmpOut.close();

    byte[] picture=tmpOut.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(picture.length);
```

this code is okay,but my internet connect is very very bad,

so ,I maybe get a broken picture like this:

[image]

How can I ensure the picture file is complete ?

I think you can add this code to try and test this:

`if (len == -1) {` change to `if (len == -1 || (int)(Math.random()*100)==1 ) {`

full test code:

```
    URL url=new URL("http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png");
    InputStream in=url.openStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream tmpOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[512];
    int len;
    while (true) {
        len = in.read(buf);
        if (len == -1 || (int)(Math.random()*100)==1 ) {
            break;
        }
        tmpOut.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    tmpOut.close();
    byte[] picture =tmpOut.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(picture.length);
```

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into using the [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) class for loading images - it takes care of a lot of these details for you:

```
Image image;
try {    
  URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png");
  image = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [URL.openConnection()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) instead
You get an [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) object on which you can query the content length (if provided) ([URLConnection.getContentLength()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29)). That would help in most case.

In the other case you can analyze the image header to get its length, but that would require a dedicated analyzer for each format.